# type casting error in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, types, casting

I am attempting to have a write a class that simulates different frequency signals. I would like for the class to take the type of object that I am testing as a parameter, in order to test methods within that calling class. I am getting an error when I try to type cast myObject as myType. Obviously I am doing this incorrectly. I have omitted much of the superfluous code in this class, as to focus on the context of my question.

```
           public MaxFinderTestChannel(TestSignals signal, Object ob)
    {
        myType = ob.GetType();
        myObject =  ob as myType; 

        switch (signal)
        {
            case TestSignals.Linear:
                {
                    constant = 1;
                    for (double dd = 0.0; dd <= 5 * Math.PI; dd += .001)
                    {
                        x = dd;
                        values.Add(x);
                        y = x + constant;
                        values.Add(y);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case TestSignals.NegativeSine:
                {
                    constant = -1;
                    for (double dd = 0.0; dd <= 5 * Math.PI; dd += .001)
                    {
                        x = dd;
                        values.Add(x);
                        y = Math.Sin(25 * x) + constant;
                        values.Add(y);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case TestSignals.Parabola:
                {
                    constant = 2;
                    for (double dd = (-Math.PI); dd <= Math.PI; dd += .1)
                    {
                        x = dd;
                        values.Add(x);
                        y = Math.Pow(x, 2) + constant;
                        values.Add(y);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case TestSignals.Sine:
                {
                    constant = 1;
                    for (double dd = 0.0; dd <= 5 * Math.PI; dd += .001)
                    {
                        x = dd;
                        values.Add(x);
                        y = Math.Sin(25 * x) + constant;
                        values.Add(y);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid signal type:" + this.Name.ToString());
        }
        pulseTrain = values.ToArray();
    }


    public virtual bool EnumDataPoints(bool eventsOnly, double startTime, double duration, Collection<ISampleProcessor> sampleProcessors)
    {
            for (double time = timestamp; !breakloop && time < endtime; time += .001)
            {
                time = Math.Round(time, 4);
                if (time == timestamp)
                {
                    if (myObject.Compute(time, ref value) == false) { breakloop = true; }
                    timestamp = Math.Round(pulseTrain[index], 4);
                    if (index < pulseTrain.Length - 1) { index++; }
                    value = Math.Round(pulseTrain[index], 4);
                    if (index < pulseTrain.Length - 1) { index++; }
                }
            }
        return !breakloop;
    }
```

The problem is that I get a compile error when I attempt to loop through my timestamps. The Compute() method is enforced by a specific interface, and several different concrete classes use this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a generic method ? :

```
public MaxFinderTestChannel<T>(TestSignals signal, T ob) where T : ITheInterface 
{
     myObject =  ob ;
    ...
```

ITheInterface being your Interface defining the Compute() method

Comment: I appreciate that. I knew generics would be the way, but being a JAVA developer I wasnt quite sure of the way to go about it

Comment: Actually there is another issue where even generics won't do the trick : if the object you pass as a parameter is unknown until runtime, in such case you will have to pass the object's Type dynamically (at runtime) tell me if it's the case

Comment: actually this did the trick, but I understand your point. I had to limit the range of interfaces due to the potential error of implicit conversion. For my test case purposes, this was the solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @david_jr you should probably accept the answer if it helps. The question must be marked as resolved.